# Не могу получить ObjectInput/OutputStream

Tags: java, многопоточность, сокет, потоки-данных

Привет) Пишу приложение - в отельном модуле сервер, в отдельном клиент.
Общаются они между собой через паттерн Медиатор:

```
@Slf4j
public final class Mediator {

    public void sendMessage(ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream, Object msg){
        try {
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(msg);
            objectOutputStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          log.error("IN sendMessage - {}", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public Object acceptMessage(ObjectInputStream objectInputStream) {

        Object obj = null;

        try {
            obj = objectInputStream.readObject();

        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            log.error("IN acceptMessage - {}", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Сам этот медиатор находится в ретьем общем модуле.

Листинг клиента:

```
try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8080);

            ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            ClientApplication clientApplication = new ClientApplication(inputStream, outputStream, configPath);
            clientApplication.run();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Здесь он виснет сразу после строки с Сокетом!!

Листинг сервера:

```
@Slf4j
public class Connection implements Runnable {

    private final List<Purchase> purchases;
    private final Catalog catalog;
    private final Socket socket;

    private final ProductService productService;
    private final ThreadLocal<Mediator> mediator;

    private ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;
    private ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;

    public Connection(Socket sender, List<Purchase> purchases, Catalog catalog) {
        this.purchases = purchases;
        this.catalog = catalog;
        this.socket = sender;

        this.productService = new ProductServiceImpl();

        this.mediator = new ThreadLocal<>();
        mediator.set(new Mediator());

        openConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            Object msg = mediator.get().acceptMessage(objectInputStream);

            if (msg instanceof String) {

                String message = (String) msg;

                if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("get catalog")){
                    mediator.get().sendMessage(objectOutputStream, catalog);

                } else if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("get purchases")) {
                    mediator.get().sendMessage(objectOutputStream, purchases);
                }

            } else if (msg instanceof PurchaseDto) {
                PurchaseDto dto = (PurchaseDto) mediator.get().acceptMessage(objectInputStream);

                List<Product> products = Arrays.stream(dto.getProductsId())
                        .mapToObj(productService::findById)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

                Purchase purchase = PurchaseFactory.createPurchase();
                products.forEach(purchase::addProduct);
                purchases.add(purchase);

            }

        }

    }

    private void openConnection() {
        try {
            this.objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            this.objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Opening connection error - {}", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

-----------------------------------------------

@Slf4j
public class Main {

    private static final List<Purchase> purchases = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
    private static final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    private final static int PORT = 8080;
    private final static Catalog catalog = CatalogFactory.create();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Stream.of(
                new ExecuteThread(purchases),
                new CheckoutThread(purchases)
        ).forEach(executorService::execute);

        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT)) {

            while (true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                executorService.execute(new Connection(socket, purchases,catalog));

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Пока я пыталась пофиксить, немного некрасиво оставила, например - использование пула потоков совместно с thread local

Объясните, почему не работает? Как мне заставить его открыть наконец потоки?

**UPD**: я убрала все, оставив только подключение. - не работает, не в медиаторе дело

**UPD**:я прям все убрала, оставив только попытку получить поток- по-прежнему не хочет. Только с Datanput/OutputStream работает

Comment: Я так понял проблема решена. Посмотрите про блокирующие и неблокирующие потоки ввода\вывода. И лучше в отдельный поток их вынесите.

Answer (score 0):

Полдня потрачено, но, блин

Ответ: **поменять местами в клиенте порядок получения стримов**

Сначала out, потом in